# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Mumbai to Dubai'

Tags: python, forms, flask

When i perform this command

```
valueReturned = int(request.form.get("name"))
```

where this name is a select tag, i am getting a value error stating

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Mumbai to Dubai'**

This is my select code.

```
<select name="name">
        {% for flight in flights %}
        <option id="{{flight.id}}">{{flight.origin}} to {{flight.destination}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

And what does the compiler selects from the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Since your option doesn't contain a `value` attribute, the text of the option is used as the value. I think you meant meant to use `value` rather than `id`

```
        <option value="{{flight.id}}">{{flight.origin}} to {{flight.destination}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

error is caused because you parse to int string "Mumbai to Dubai". you request attribute 'name' from select and you dont have got any values in options. So you try to parse this:

```
{{flight.origin}} to {{flight.destination}}
```

try to put values to option tags:

```
<select name="name">
    {% for flight in flights %}
        <option value="{{flight.id}}">{{flight.origin}} to {{flight.destination}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

change a bit this statement:

```
 valueReturned = int(request.form["name"])
```

i suppose that flight.id is a number - string but number. And then you will have got int method working without errors